# Insert data into Cassandra from Pig using list datatype fails

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, apache-pig, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I have the following scenario:

Table in Cassandra:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_st_test (
  id int,
  email list<text>,
  PRIMARY KEY ((id));
```

PIG Code:

```
teste = LOAD 'cql://main/tb_st_test' USING CqlStorage();

testing = FOREACH teste GENERATE $0 as cod, ['emailtest@test.com'] as field:();

insert_test = 
FOREACH testing GENERATE
TOTUPLE(
TOTUPLE('id',cod)
),
TOTUPLE(field);

STORE insert_test INTO 'cql://main/tb_st_test?output_query=UPDATE tb_st_test set email %3D%3F' USING CqlStorage();
```

The idea here is to read the table tb_st_test, get the key values, and update the field email.
But when I run the script I get the following error:

### Backend error message

```
java.io.IOException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlRecordWriter$RangeClient.run(CqlRecordWriter.java:256)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:129)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:362)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:284)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:191)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_execute_prepared_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1820)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.execute_prepared_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1805)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlRecordWriter$RangeClient.run(CqlRecordWriter.java:240)
```

Does anyone know what it is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The insert_test format is wrong, for list collection format should be TOTUPLE(TOUTUPLE('some email', 'email2')). check https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5867